# Serving two streamlit apps in parallel with nginx results in 403 or 404

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-403, streamlit

First time using nginx here and it seems I'm missing something.

I have two Streamlit apps being served on ports 8501 and 8502 respectively. I can access either by going to their respective : directly. I also have a URL pointing to the EC2 instance from where they are served.

But when routing `/app1` and `/app2` locations, nginx gives me either 403 and stops or 404 and returns to `/`. **I imagine there is something wrong with nginx configuration. Can someone please help me set it up correctly - or point me to somewhere else where my problem may be?**

Here are the contents of the `default` file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name = <my domain>;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # Required to enable Streamlit's websockets (?)
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 2h;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/;
    }

    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8502/;
    }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `/` is commented out above (I don't need a `/`, I could return a 404 on that)
- As it is above, both locations result in 403
- Removing the trailing “/” from the address of the proxy_pass in the locations results in 404

I tried naming the `baseUrlPath` in each app's `.streamlit/config.toml` file (and adding that to the location proxy_pass) but it didn't help. Below is what I currently have on each app's config.toml:

```
[logger]
level = "debug"

[server]
port = 8501
#baseUrlPath = "app1"
headless = true
enableCORS = false
enableXsrfProtection = false
```

(except with port 8502 for app2)

Thanks for any insights!

---

UPDATE: Got it to work!

Two changes, I think the first one is what made the difference, but may have been something in the second:

1. Uncommented the `baseUrlPath` on both Streamlit configs and added `/app1` and `/app2` to their respective `proxy_pass` calls (without the trailing `/`)
2. From [this solution](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-docker-nginx-ssl-https/2195/6), added all the lines suggested (previously I had only half of them), and under each location (rather than for the whole server as above, from where I thought each location would have inherited it).

I'll still test later whether all these lines are really required, and whether they can be inherited from the server definition - but for now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Got it to work!

Two changes, I think the first one is what made the difference, but may have been something in the second:

```
Uncommented the baseUrlPath on both Streamlit configs and added /app1 and /app2 to their respective proxy_pass calls (without the trailing /)
From this solution, added all the lines suggested (previously I had only half of them), and under each location (rather than for the whole server as above, from where I thought each location would have inherited it).
```

I'll still test later whether all these lines are really required, and whether they can be inherited from the server definition - but for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
location ~* ^/app1/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

That should at least proxy the request `domain.com/app1/test/index.html` to `127.0.0.1:8501/test/index.html` - so remove the app1 part.

If that is not working you should have a look inside the logs. At first if nginx is getting the request successfull and then have a look inside the logs of your application - which request it gets and how this request should look like to be successfull.

---

EDIT:

You could also try the following:

```
location /app1 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501; # No trailing slash here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try looking at the logs and compare.
However forgive my poor knowledge of networking but I don't see how the suggestion above would help; there is no `domain.com/app1/test/index.html` request, unless nginx is building that by default - does it do that?
The request coming is simply `domain.com/app1` , that's all there is and all that should be. The app is also not expecting any arguments after the port.

Comment: Does your streamlit application only serves at the root `/` and has no subpages? Ofc the above should also work with `domain.com/app1`. If you only want to get this result you could try if my edit works.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, but then I get 404 for both links, and redirected to `location \`

I can make Streamlit serve at `ip:port/app1` instead of just `ip:port` but I don't think there's an index file or any other file to specify.

Comment: thanks for the help! It's working now, see update above / new answer posted.